# I am having a syntax error in the MERGE statement

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres 12.3 and find an error in a simple MERGE statement like below:

```
MERGE INTO lkup_language a
   USING (SELECT *
            FROM dblc_stg.stg_lkup_home_language
           WHERE home_lang_code NOT IN (SELECT   home_lang_code
                                           FROM dblc_stg.stg_lkup_home_language
                                       GROUP BY home_lang_code
                                         HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)) b
   ON (a.language_cd = b.home_lang_code)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (a.language_key, a.language_cd, a.language_desc)
      VALUES (NEXTVAL('SEQ_LKUP_LANGUAGE'),b.home_lang_code, b.home_lang_desc)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET a.language_desc = b.home_lang_desc   ;
```

I hope I get some help
Thanks
Ajay

Comment: Postgres does not have `MERGE`. See `ON CONFLICT` here [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the specific error message you are receiving to your question as well.

Comment: MERGE doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, the message makes sense.

Comment: You can't just run an Oracle statement in Postgres and expect it to work. Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much !! I spent so much time yesterday on this one, all wasted. I am just trying to convert my oracle script into postgres and there are so many things I am still struggling with.

Comment: All valid SQL commands [are listed in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)